# Simple contract fails to deploy to Sepolia

Tags: solidity, remix, contract-deployment, bytes, sepolia

I am trying to deploy a very simple contract to Sepolia.

Here is the code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.18;

    contract Object {
        bytes32 private UID;
        bytes private Desc;

        constructor(bytes32 _UID, bytes memory _Desc) {
            UID             = _UID;
            Desc            = _Desc;
            }

        function getUID() view public returns (bytes32) {
            return UID;
            }

        function getDesc() view public returns (bytes memory) {
            return Desc;
            }
    }
```

This compiles fine and appears to work, but when I try and deploy it on Remix on Sepolia (or VM) it does not work. No error message, it just does not deploy.

Is there a problem with the code or is it an issue with Remix?

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like it doesn't get deployed if you pass the incorrect data types to the constructor.

As Ethan mentioned, you can try passing something like that: _UID=0x596f7520676f7420697421000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

_DESC=0x596f7520676f7420697421000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

See this contract instance I deployed form my Sepolia account: 0x98297FDB08B661D9075345E8DCF01f7eAe607c2e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code can be deployed, maybe there is a problem with the parameters of the constructor you passed in.

You can try:

```
_UID = 0xdd440df46537b153fd7dcb3d09fe2d20ab4650728dfc389f4fe51de36a8cab06
_Desc = 0xdd440df46537b153fd7dcb3d09fe2d20ab4650728dfc389f4fe51de36a8cab06
```